# Copy entire C structure using Unsafe?

Tags: java

I've been exploring the Java Unsafe library, and so far I can see how I can copy individual fields of a structure from a serialized byte stream (for example by using `getInt()` etc.), but if I have the following (packed) structure serialized:

```
struct foo
{
  int a, b, c;
  short d, e, f;
};
```

Can I do this with a single copy from a memory address (in this case Netty `ByteBuf` instance.)? I could use JNR too if required, though I can't quite see how to connect the two yet.

Comment: `Unsafe` isn't really intended to actually be used by code outside the JDK.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I know the caveats, but, I'd like to go down this route...

Comment: In particular, making assumptions about how Java lays out the memory structure of a class is really quite dangerous and frankly unpredictable.  If you _must,_ you might load the contents into a `ByteBuffer` and implement the getters of your class by doing indexed `getInt` and `getShort` operations on that, but this is frankly extremely unlikely to pay for its own maintenance cost.

Comment: There's no point in doing that, `ByteBuf` implements the same interface. The only reason I'm looking in these dark corners, is because I'd like to see if it's possible to push decoding this structure to be *faster* than `ByteBuf`, so far, it's faster with field-by-field using Unsafe, however looking to see if I can push beyond that...

Comment: Do you have hard benchmark results showing this is a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: My code reads a packet, and then decodes it - two steps, reading a packet is out of my hand, so all I can improve is the decode, there is no other bottleneck, and yes, I'm only looking because I can see it's slower... compared to my c++ decoder, the java stuff is not in the same league, so need to muster some dark arts... I can see that the unsafe operations have improved things by about 30-40%, however it's still a good 100% slower than the c++ version...